# Why is the most probable KE for a monoatomic ideal gas exactly 1/3 of its average KE?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws

The most probable value of the kinetic energy for a monoatomic ideal gas can be calculated by setting the first derivative of the probablity density function equal to $0$, this turns out to be $\frac{1}{2}kT$ which is $\frac{1}{3}$ of the average value, $\frac{3}{2}kT$ what is the physical reason behind this?

Answer (score 6):

There is no physical reason. It's bare mathematics. The probability distribution in terms of energy is asymmetric, for it is bounded by 0 from below and not bounded at all from above. Asymmetric distributions are known to have (generally speaking) [different values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)#Example_for_a_skewed_distribution) for mean, mode, and median.
Think of the exponential distribution: its average value is some positive number, but the mode (the most probable value) is $\bf 0$.

Moreover, 3 is not even some intrinsic characteristic of the system. If you rewrite the distribution [in terms of velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution#Distribution_function) (the way it is commonly done), you'll have an altogether different situation. All of a sudden, the ratio of mean to mode is... $2\over\sqrt\pi$, how would you like that?